# ruby on rails, agile web development with rails, build method with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, build, relationship

I'm currently working through the book agile web development with rails, and I'm trying to build something on my own. On Page 126 is described how you build a relationship from one table to another:

```
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
```

I'm wondering how you can build a relationship with more than one product, so basically add two products at the same time to the cart with just on click on a add to cart button? If product is a array of two product id's, I'll get a error message.

Comment: Your question is not clear. A cart may have many products and many wheels with no problem at all. Also it isn't clear that what do you mean by your line before the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have 2 products in my store but just one button to add them both at the same time (I don't know if that makes sense, but I want to try it), but if i do that i have two product id's in my product variable. If i pass this array of product id's to the @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product) I'll get an error and thats my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do, but looping over all products and creating line items for them. Just like this:

```
@cart = current_cart
@line_items = []
params[:product_ids].each do |product_id|
  product = Product.find product_id
  @line_items << @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)
end
```

Comment: Ok that sounds good, thanks. I tried it before with a loop, but it was probably the wrong syntax, rails just drives me nuts ;), I' ll give it a try.

Comment: I tried it, but i get another error, "if @line_items.save" does not work with my array of id's, do i have to loop through that again?

Comment: This does not work because it is an array. When calling `@cart.save`, your line items should be saved automatically. This way you don't need to call save on each individual line item. Alternatively you could save all objects in `@line_items` with map: `@line_items.map(&:save)`.

Comment: ok thanks again, this is how i figured it out, i think its not pretty but it works : `while i < @line_item.length do
       @line_item[i].save
       i +=1
    end
    redirect_to @line_item[0].cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.'`